# Expanding Valence API to include facets related to the Competencies tool?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Are there any indications that the Valence API would include tie-ins to the competency function? I'm thinking something akin to polling D2L for a competency report of a student indicating completion at various levels (a singular competency, or some hierarchy). Presently there doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation related to the competencies function. Or if it IS there in some form its not jumping out at me where it lies in the shadows.

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Awesome competency reporting, including making flexible reporting available via Valence is precisely where we at D2L hope to be hitting in the future, but as you discovered, is not available quite yet.  We are initiating a wider cross-product project now to better support competencies & learning outcomes, and this request is noted.  That said, I'd also encourage you to ask your LMS admin to send in this feature request via your D2L Account Manager.